# Start a service from another computer

Tags: vb.net, service, remote-access

I have a project in which we would like to do the following :

- Install a service that perform several tasks. this would be put on Computer A and B
- Another computer C serves as a witness;
- At start, only A is running because the work it performs cannot be duplicated;
- Should A fail, then B must start. C should be the one that verify is one is running or not;
- Sholud A return back up after a fail, then B still runs and A is on stand-by;
- Should B then fail, C start A services,
- And So On.

Is it possible, if so how ? Both A and B have a SQL server 2008 on them but this part is taken care of for us.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT : I tried stopping a service (that I know is running) and it dosn't seem to work :

```
    Dim path As ManagementPath = New ManagementPath
    path.Server = System.Environment.MachineName
    path.NamespacePath = "root\CIMV2"
    path.RelativePath = "Win32_service.Name='" + strServiceName + "'"
    Dim service As ManagementObject = New ManagementObject(path)
    Dim temp As ManagementBaseObject = service.InvokeMethod("StopService", Nothing, Nothing)
```

In this case, strServiceName is "CommunicationInterface" which is a service I recently add and started manually.

I am running under windows 7.

Comment: At which layer do you need to implement this?

Comment: On Windows this is called Microsoft Cluster Service or Veritas Cluster Server.  On AIX it is HACMP or PowerHA.  There are a variety of monitors on Linux including Red Hat Cluster or Veritas again.  Do you not know about these or are you trying to get a "poor man's cluster" and avoid the license cost?  To do this right is a non-trivial project, which is why there are so many vendor options available.

Comment: I am just trying to make things work :p I'll use whatever's good but since I don't know that field, there might be a lot of things I overlooked. This is wher you come in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the services to not start automatically and then have the C computer start them as needed using the WMI class [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can also use this class to query if the services are running or not.

Look at the [StartService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [StopService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods as well as the `State` property.

Here's some sample code: [Service Management in VB.NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/tocontrolservicesrunninginasystem12282006033414AM/tocontrolservicesrunninginasystem.aspx)

Comment: That would be great, but how we poll the services from another computer ?

Comment: @David: The C computer would connect to A and/or B using WMI and the using `Win32_Service.State` to check the state of the service you're interested in. If you look at the sample code from my answer, just change `System.Environment.MachineName` to the name of A or B to connect to them remotely.

Comment: Man, if this works, I'm giving up 2 upvotes... Oh right, I can't :(

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Windows Server 2008 Failover Clusters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182338.aspx). From that page:

> A failover cluster is a group of
>   independent computers that work
>   together to increase the availability
>   of applications and services. The
>   clustered servers (called nodes) are
>   connected by physical cables and by
>   software. If one of the cluster nodes
>   fails, another node begins to provide
>   service (a process known as failover).
>   Users experience a minimum of
>   disruptions in service.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Is this something that must be done by coding or can this be setup some other way. I have no knowledge of anything of the sort.

Comment: David - it can be done by coding. You basically make your application "cluster-aware" by implementing a set of interfaces that the failover cluster subsystem can call into when it "wants" to perform a failover.

Comment: Ok. I'll check that. Ideal case is that I can do it with as little code as possible or no code at all. Time restreint is one but also I am far from being an expert at that kind of thing.